# .net sql exception handling - how to get the sp parameter/values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception

In .net development what the best solution to catch the store procedure's parameter/values(or whole statement maybe) from the exception when there is a error for executing the store procedure?

Any generic solutions?

environment---
c#, .net, linq to sql, store procedure, wcf service

Thanks

code sample

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCountries()
{
  using (var db = new L2SDataContext(_connectionString))
  {
    var result = db.prime_ui_country_get();

    return result.Select(item => item.country).ToList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you handling errors inside the stored procedure?

Comment: I'd suggest that you simply grab the parameters from the code that is calling the stored procedure.  Your question leads me to believe that you haven't structured things correctly.  We'll need to see a bit of code on how you call the proc

Comment: no. but I am looking for all possible solutions, do I have to raise it in each single sp to raise exception including the parameter/values? @JeffO

Comment: thanks. added a code sample in the DAL class @ChrisLively

Comment: Where is your exception handling code?  Normally you put it right at the point where you are calling this proc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get error info (stored procedure name etc) from the [SqlException.Errors Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx). As for the parameters/values, why not just use the SqlCommand object??